# Bash: Define dynamic functions inside another function

Tags: bash, shell, vim

As my question seems a little loaded, I'll just explain what I try to do.
I often use *imprisoning* programs like `bash`, which put me inside *another  context*. (e.g. text editors like `vim` or shells like `irb` or `python -i`.

There I usually daddle around for a bit, until I put the program to sleep with `^Z`. At that point, I'm back inside my normal `bash` shell, *the mothership*.

At some point I may want to call `irb` or `vim` again, however being absentminded as I am, I will usually already have forgotten about my sleeping instance of that program. Even if I haven't, my hands usually act quicker than my brain can think *Let's look up that jobspec!*

Now I have two instances of the same program running in the same `shell` instance. And now `goto 1`: I will `^Z` again, forget about it, run another instance, etc.pp.

So I thought I'd make it so that when I call `vim`:

- when there are more than 1 instances of `vim` open, be confused
- when there is already an instance of `vim` open, open up that one
- when there is no instance of `vim` open, open up a new one
- when I really want to open the same program twice, I can do so with `vim!`

Here's my program:

```
_make_escapable() {
    "$1"() {
        declare INSTANCES_OF_CMD=$(jobs | grep -c "\S\+Stopped\+\S\+\s\+$1")

        case ${INSTANCES_OF_CMD} in
            0)
                command "$1" "$@"
                ;;
            1)
                if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
                    %"$1"
                    return 0
                else
                    echo "Can't open other files with a running instance of $1"'!' 1>&2
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                echo "You have multiple instances of $1 running. Choose one." 1>&2
                ;;
        esac
    }

    alias "$1"'!'="command $1"
}

_make_escapable 'vim'
_make_escapable 'irb'
```

As you can see, I want to automate that functionality. The thing is that there is no parameter expansion for function names (it seems). I could do a new function for every one program, but I'd rather much have a nice interface to do this. *Does anybody know how to this?*

Comment: have you thought of using vim ``--remote`` option?  This will open vim in a client server mode, where all opened buffers are accessible from all client instances.

Comment: Okay I tested `--remote` just now, but I doesn't really fit my workflow. I use tmux so I already a *server* running with my worksuite inside of it. I think of `tmux` sessions as contexts from which I can work on a specific `thing`. If I want to work on something else, I'd change the *session* and have a new slate to work with, without abandoning my old one.

Comment: i use tmux too, one session per project, and i find the ability to use ``emacsclient`` and ``vim --remote`` great, specially for sharing clipboards across sessions.

Comment: Honestly, job control is left over from a time when things like `tmux` (or `xterm`s in a GUI, for that matter) weren't available. There's not much need to put programs like `vi` in the background after you've started them just to get back to the shell.

Comment: @Meitham Thanks for your tipp, I never really looked into emacs, as I felt Vim was enought but I certainly intend to one day. Also sharing clipboards sounds like a great idea.

Comment: @chepner And that's why I want to make it as comfortable as possible

Comment: One interesting solution would be to use `irb` from inside `vim` (and a shell from inside Vim as well).  The `conque` plugin allows for that, it uses Vim tabs to run commands.  Another option is to use `neovim`, see [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/how-do-i-open-a-shell-in-only-one-tab-in-vim) on vi.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_make_escapable() {
    alias make_function="$1"'() { declare INSTANCES_OF_CMD=$(jobs | grep -c "\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+'"$1"'") &&
        case ${INSTANCES_OF_CMD} in
            0) command '"$@"' "$@" ;;
            1) if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then %'"$1"'; return 0 ; else echo ''Cannot use parameters with running instance of '"$1"'''; fi ;;
            *) echo ''You have multiple instances of '"$1"' running. Choose one.'' 1>&2 ;;
        esac; }'
    eval make_function
    unalias make_function

    alias "$1"'!'='command '"$1"
}

_make_escapable 'vim'
_make_escapable 'irb'
_make_escapable 'ghci' '-v0'
```

This will take any command and make it *fleeable*, like I described it in my question.

It first constructs the function definition using an alias and then executes the alias, defining the function.